# How can I sort the objects in the hierarchy also after filtered them in the search bar?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class CustomHierarchy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, 2);
    public static Color gameObjectFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabOrgFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabModFontColor = Color.white;
    public static Color inActiveColor = new Color(0.01f, 0.4f, 0.25f);
    public static Color meshRendererColor = Color.yellow;

    static CustomHierarchy()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI;
    }
    private static void HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI(int instanceID, Rect selectionRect)
    {
        Color fontColor = gameObjectFontColor;
        Color backgroundColor = new Color(.76f, .76f, .76f);
        FontStyle styleFont = FontStyle.Normal;
        var obj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID);
        GameObject gameObj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID) as GameObject;

        if (Selection.instanceIDs.Contains(instanceID))
        {
            backgroundColor = new Color(0.24f, 0.48f, 0.90f);
        }
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var prefabType = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType(obj);
            if (gameObj.activeInHierarchy == false)
            {
                backgroundColor = inActiveColor;
            }

            if (prefabType == PrefabType.PrefabInstance)
            {
                styleFont = FontStyle.Bold;
                PropertyModification[] prefabMods = PrefabUtility.GetPropertyModifications(obj);
                foreach (PropertyModification prefabMod in prefabMods)
                {
                    if (prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_Name" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.w" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_RootOrder" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_IsActive")
                    {
                        if (HasAllComponents(gameObj, typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(BoxCollider)))
                        {
                            gameObj.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
                            fontColor = meshRendererColor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fontColor = prefabModFontColor;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (fontColor != prefabModFontColor)
                {
                    if (HasAllComponents(gameObj, typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(BoxCollider)))
                    {
                        gameObj.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
                        fontColor = meshRendererColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fontColor = prefabOrgFontColor;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (HasAllComponents(gameObj, typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(BoxCollider)))
                {
                    gameObj.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
                    fontColor = meshRendererColor;
                }
            }
            Rect offsetRect = new Rect(selectionRect.position + offset, selectionRect.size);
            EditorGUI.DrawRect(selectionRect, backgroundColor);
            EditorGUI.LabelField(offsetRect, obj.name, new GUIStyle()
            {
                normal = new GUIStyleState() { textColor = fontColor },
                fontStyle = styleFont
            }
            );
        }
    }

    public static bool HasAllComponents(GameObject gameObject, params System.Type[] types)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
        {
            if (gameObject.GetComponent(types[i]) == null)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I did in some places:

```
gameObj.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
```

It does working in the main root of the hierarchy there is one object in yellow and he is moving to the top.

But when I filter objects by name in the search bar for example typing: Corridor
There are many objects and none of them is moving to the top.
I want that all the objects in yellow in all the places I added:

```
gameObj.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
```

Will move to the top.
So if for example there are 30 objects in yellow that are HasAllComponents move all of them to the top even when filtering.

Answer (score 1):

The search bar is a *view* filter; it has no effect on the *state* of your object hierarchies. SetSiblingIndex doesn't know anything about search view so it can't reorder things in there. It can only reorder objects that share the same parent.

If you truly have a good reason to modify your object hierarchy and move GameObjects around based on the result of a search, you could parent all the currently selected objects to the same container object near the top of your Scene hierarchy so they all show up first in searches and can then be re-ordered relative to one another.

```
gameObj.transform.SetParent(someContainerGameObject.transform);
```

Or you could write your own custom editor window that can search and display in whatever order you want without affecting the Scene hierarchy at all.

**Edit:** More information about asset searching:

[AssetDatabase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html) can be used in editor code to search the entire project library instead of the Scene. Searching is extremely fast even with thousands of assets, so something like this is reasonable to do:

```
AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:GameObject");
```

Which will give you guid strings you can turn into object references using AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath() and AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(). Once you have the GameObject references, you can check each one with your HasAllComponents method.

If you want to make changes to them, you either a) update your script to do things like AddComponent on them automatically if needed, or b) wrap all the code in a new Editor Window that lists those objects for easy selection in the editor, or c) you can create a new selection automatically through code.

Explaining the details of each option is beyond the scope of this question, but this should get you started.

Comment: The reason I want to modify the objects and move around is that this gameObjects inside each place that HasAllComponents I want to easy find them and modify them like add to them another component/s or remove component/s. The problem is that in the Hierarchy searcher you can't find and filter objects with multiple components. The idea is to identify easy the objects with multiple components.

Comment: How can I make a searcher over EditorWindow ? I googled didn't find any. I could make a searcher in editorwindow that filter and search in the hierarchy. But how can I make my own searcher with database without affecting the scene hierarchy ?

Comment: Edited the answer with some more information that may help.